# Why js and css file is valid when they are imported on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website which import some js and css files on the head tag, but when I open the website by chrome,The entire page layout is completely wrong and looks like js and css files is valid. Who can help me? Thanks.

**some problem page's code as follow,every js and css files in my code are available**

you can try some url

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--禁用移动设备缩放  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"> -->
<script src="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/css/swiper.min.css">
</head>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: "looks like js and css files is valid".  Do you mean "invalid"?

Comment: So what do you see in the JavaScript console? Are there error messages? When you look at the network tab, is everything loading?

Comment: sorry,I input a mistake word, it's invalid. JS consolo don't have any error messages. Every js css and image files have been loaded in the network tab.

Comment: http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/15-09-29560a833ac5600.html